# Elasticsearch ignores logger settings

Tags: logging, elasticsearch

I'm trying to reconfigure the elasticsearch logs.
The level that I would like to have is `INFO`, but it stays on `DEBUG`.

An example is:

```
[2016-09-13 15:25:15,980][DEBUG][action.bulk              ] [nodename...] ...
```

The cluster has right now this transient configuration:

```
{
  "persistent": {},
  "transient": {
    "cluster": {
      "routing": {
        "allocation": {
          "disable_allocation": "false",
          "enable": "all"
        }
      }
    },
    "logger": {
      "_root": "INFO",
      "cluster": {
        "action": {
          "shard": "INFO"
        }
      },
      "search.action": {
        "type": "INFO"
      },
      "indices": {
        "recovery": "INFO"
      },
      "search": "INFO",
      "bulk.action": "INFO",
      "discovery": "INFO",
      "bulk": "INFO"
    }
  }
```

which seems to be ignored.
The ES version is 1.7.1

Comment: `bulk.action` should be `action.bulk`

Comment: @val thanks for your comment. It seems that it worked. 
Now I'm guessing why the cluster accepted the wrong settings.

Comment: it's not a wrong setting, simply one that that doesn't have any effect. but it's definitely possible that you have a `bulk.action.Something` class somewhere, ES has no way to know that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help :-)